# Chain Selectors are not working properly in webdriver.io

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

i have my dom like the below , i am able to get the first element

[image]

this is what i am trying to get the 2nd and 3rd element but getting null

[image]

here is the actual code in my cucumber step definitions.

```
When('I click on an option', async function() {
const items = '.entry';
await browser.waitForExist(items);
await browser.click('.entry:nth-child(2)');
});
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: `nth-child()` doesn't work like that. Pull the collection of all elements and just click on the 2nd by index, etc.

Comment: if we use queryselector we can pull the list of elements , but how to do that with webdriver , please see this doc http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#Chain-Selectors from webdriver.io

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)